# Cannot boot alternate boot environment in openindiana

Tags: boot, grub, zfs, solaris, openindiana

i have installed two boot environment on my openindiana hipster 202004 server, rpool and rpool1.
These are the steps i followed for my second boot environment:

`zpool create -f rpool1 c5t3d0s0`

`beadm create -p rpool1 oihipster`

`installgrub /boot/grub/stage1 /boot/grub/stage2 /dev/rdsk/c5t3d0s0`

`zpool set bootfs=rpool1/ROOT/oihipster rpool1`

`beadm activate oihipster`

then restart and set the boot priority to the hard disk hosting the second boot environment. but after that it doesn't boot with error No boot device found!!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What hardware?  What disk is your original root pool on?  Is your new drive on a bootable controller?

Comment: Thanks for you reply Andrew. I've tested with many hard disks but right now in my test environment I have two Seagate Barracuda SSD 250GB as my rpool which are mirrored. I have added a SanDisk SSD 120GB and did the steps I mentioned on them. During the steps I receive no error and all hard drives are selectable in BIOS as boot disks. but when I want to boot from the new BE i installed on SanDisk it wont boot.
I don't know if it helps or not but same test with same hardware was successful on OmniOS. I don't know what's the problem in OpenIndiana!
Thanks